# Need to find out the type of space used in a string

Tags: string, whitespace

I have an issue with doing a search.

My data has a space like this (between Ground and the Hyphen)
        Ground - 
but I can't replicate it. it isn't a normal space or a tab and I have tried all the zero white space characters i know. And most text styling assumes it is a normal space and converts it so (including StackOverflow)

The only way I can show it even exists is through notepad++

[image: demo of issue]

As you can see normal spaces have an orange dot but this does not. further more it thinks it is part of the word.

[image: demo2]
[image: demo3]

unfortunately I cant change the source data so cant change these weird spaces to normal spaces. so I need a search that includes them to return results. I just don't know how to replicate that space.

Any ideas would be most helpful.

Comment: Why don’t you print out the chat code at that position?

Comment: Sorry how do you mean?